# Laravel 5.4 eloquent hasMany and subsequent PHP to check an approval status

Tags: php, sql, laravel, foreach, eloquent

I have two models, Email and EmailReview. Email hasMany EmailReviews. This query:

```
$data = Email::with('emailReviews')->where('created_by', '=', $personId)->get();
```

returns a collection of a specific person's `emails` that have a `review_group_type` of either `approval` or `feedback` and a relationship of `email_reviews` that have an approved property of either true, false or null. I'm looking for the cleanest way to check if the email is an approval email and all of the reviews in the collection have their approved column set to true in order to set an approval status for each email i.e., `$email->approvalStatus`. Some emails will also not have reviews yet, so I'll need to check for that. Something along these lines, but it's clearly getting ugly and I'm having a hard time getting my end result:

```
if ($data->review_group_type === 'approval') {
        foreach($data as $email) {
            if (!is_null($email->email_reviews)) 
            foreach($email->email_reviews as $review) {

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on @Salama96 response and going a little bit further, you can do this:

```
$data = Email::with('emailReviews')
        ->where(['created_by'=>$personId,'review_group_type'=>'approval'])
        ->has('emailReviews')
        ->get()
        ->map(function ($email){
           // Here, you check if all the emailReviews are 'true'
           $reviewsStatus = $email->emailReviews->pluck('approved')->unique();
           if ($reviewsStatus->count() == 1 AND $reviewsStatus->first())
           {
               $email->approvalStatus = true;
           }

           return $email;
        });
    }
```

PS: Haven't test it properly, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly. I knew there was an eloquent way to do and this is spot on.

Comment: Do you have a recommended way of updating it to get all emails, regardless of their review_group_type and regardless of whether or not they have emailReviews and still be able to set the approvalStatus? In this case I'd want to set the status to either `approved` or `pending approval`

Comment: Something along these lines:                                                              `$data = Email::with('emailReviews')
        ->where('created_by', '=', $personId)
        ->get()
        ->map(function ($email) {
            $reviewsStatus = $email->emailReviews->pluck('approved')->unique();
            if ($reviewsStatus->count() == 1 and $reviewsStatus->first()) {
                $email->approvalStatus = 'Approved';
            } else {
                $email->approvalStatus = 'Pending Approval';
            }

            return $email;
        });`

Comment: Actually never mind, exactly that works perfectly! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify your query to be like this :

```
$data = Email::with('emailReviews')
 ->where(['created_by'=>$personId,'review_group_type'=>'approval'])
 ->has('emailReviews')->get();
```

Here you are going to get all emails created by specific person with an approval condition and have emailReviews